# EComDev_PHPUnit EAV Attribute Fixture Yaml Format

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, ecomdev-phpunit, phpunit

I need to create a dummy customer attribute in the `eav/attributes` table using an fixture provided by EcomDev_PHPUnit.

I tried using the tables fixture *also this is the data I need to provide*, but this clears the entire table and only leaves my one fixture which is not of great use.

```
tables:
  eav/attribute:
    - attribute_id: 50000
      entity_type_id: 1
      attribute_code: "required_fixture_attr"
      backend_type: "varchar"
      frontend_input: "text"
      frontend_label: "Customer Fixture Attr"
      is_required: 1
      is_user_defined: 0
      is_unique: 0
```

I can't find any documentation on how to use the `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Model_Fixture_Processor_Attributes` in an acceptable YAML format.

Does anybody know the format, or have another method of adding an attribute to the `eav_attributes` table so I am not dependant on the default attributes shipped with Magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I saw the Table fixture removes all data from table when you use that fixture.

One solution you could try is to get rid of fixture in this case and add your attribute programatically in test `setUp()` method.